# I am trying to use rocksdb as storage backend for caching purpose

Tags: storage, space

i wonder if the fs storage space used by rocksdb is managed by filesystem or rocksdb itself? if the storage space is managed by the underlying filesystem, then the overhead to allocate/release storage space will be a non trival problem. Further, the I/O performance of fs will get worse with long-time running because of storage pieces caused by steady allocation and releasing.

Answer (score 0):

RocksDB has *some notion* of space management. Look into the [max_size_amplification_percent](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-Tuning-Guide#universal-compaction) option.